# C pointer to a stack is causing warnings

Tags: c

The following code is generating pointer warnings and I am not sure how to fix it?

```
gcc -std=c11 -pg -g3 -ggdb -W -Wall -lefence  -I.  -o main.o -c main.c
main.c: In function ‘push_state’:
main.c:15:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    *++s->point = s->top;
                ^
main.c: In function ‘pop_state’:
main.c:19:11: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
    s->top=*s->point--;
           ^
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct stack{
   int **point;      // pointer to location in memory
   int *memory[24];  // stack memory
   int top;
   int i;
}Stack;


void push_state(Stack *s){
   s->top=s->i++;
   *++s->point = s->top;
};

void pop_state(Stack *s){
   s->top = *s->point--;
};

void get_top(Stack *s){
   printf("Stack top: %d\n",s->top);
};

void start(){
   Stack s;
   s.point=&s.memory[0];
   s.i=0;

   push_state(&s);
   get_top(&s);
   pop_state(&s);
   get_top(&s);
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
   start();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have your indirection, `*`, quite wrong. Read up how pointers should be accessed, and try again. Feel free to ask questions if you're confused on topics though.

One starter, your memory for the stack shouldn't have a `*` in the declaration, unless your goal is to store "pointers to integers" in your 24-element array.

Comment: I'm sorry but not a single line of this makes any sense. You don't need to fix pointer warnings in this code. It's all wrong from the very beginning to the very end. You need to scrap it in its entirety and start over.

Comment: It takes a certain amount of bravado (and confidence that you know what you're doing) to write `*++s->point = s->top;`.  I would seldom try to do that much in a single operation.

Comment: Are you storing `int *` in your stack, or `int`?  You've got `int *memory[24];` in your structure, but do you need `int memory[24];` instead?  The `point` would become `int *point;` then, probably, simplifying life.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the warning, `t->top` is a integer but `*++s->point` is a pointer, so you cant convert integer to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this;

```
typedef struct stack{
   int **point;      // pointer to location in memory
   int *memory[24];  // stack memory
   int *top;
   int i;
}Stack;


void push_state(Stack *s){
   s->top=s->memory[s->i++];
   *++s->point = s->top;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a solution to my problem:
The problem was that `s.point=&s.memory[0];` was not correct it should be `s.point=s.memory;` also `**point` was not correct it should be `*point` and `*memory[24];` should be `*memory` and declared dynamically. Thanks Jonathan Leffler for making me go back and rethink it by removing the extra `*` from `**point`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define push(s) (*++s->point = s->top)
#define pop(s)   (*s->point--)
#define look(s) (*s->point)

#define MALLOC(p,s) if(((p) = malloc(s * sizeof(p))) == NULL){ exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

typedef struct stack{
   int *point;      // pointer to location in memory
   int *memory;  // stack memory
   int top;
   int i;
}Stack;

void push_state(Stack *s){
   ++(s->top);
   push(s);
};

void pop_state(Stack *s){
   s->top = pop(s);
};

void look_top(Stack *s){
   printf("look %d, Stack top:  %d\n",look(s), s->top);
};

void start(){
   Stack s;
   s.top=0;

   MALLOC(s.memory,24);
   //s.point=&s.memory[0]; <- wrong assignment
   s.point=s.memory;

   push_state(&s); 
   push_state(&s); 
   push_state(&s); 
   look_top(&s);    
   pop_state(&s);  
   look_top(&s);   
   pop_state(&s);
   look_top(&s);   
   push_state(&s);
   look_top(&s);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
   start();
   return 0;
}
```